# Hyperledger fabric does not recognizes the MSP and certs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. When i tried to customize the network configuration according my needs, i'm facing that error:

```
2018-03-20 22:54:33.547 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 52c33 Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.blockchain-clone.iba"))
```

here is [configtx.yaml](https://pastebin.com/QffhgWnm) content and [cryptoconfig.yaml](https://pastebin.com/35S9MWEn) is here

What should i do to fix it?